# How to Group and count in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, count, group-by, distinct

I have a table like this

```
date        |  text | link_id
------------+-------+----------
 05-10-2014 | lorem |    2
 06-10-2014 | lorem |    4
 05-10-2014 | lorem |    4
 05-10-2014 | lorem |    5
 05-10-2014 | lorem |    5
 05-10-2014 | lorem |    5
 05-10-2014 | lorem |    5
 05-10-2014 | lorem |    5
 05-10-2014 | lorem |    6
 05-10-2014 | lorem |    4
```

I need to get the count of group from my rows here the result

```
    date    |  text | link_id  | value
------------+-------+----------+-------
 05-10-2014 | lorem |    2     |   1
 06-10-2014 | lorem |    4     |   3
 05-10-2014 | lorem |    5     |   6
```

and why if I use function

```
COUNT(DISTINCT n)
```

or only

```
COUNT()
```

it always forces me to add all `SELECT` statement to `GROUP`

and I'm only Distinct 1 row

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Select link_id, Count (link_id)
From table
Group by link_id;
```

where you should replace table with the name of your table.

Aggregate functions get applied to all rows in a group. So you first group by link_id and get groups of rows with the same link_id. Count gets applied then to each group to compute the number of rows in each group. You would get then link_id && number of rows with same link_id as result.

Please note that it is actually unclear from your question how do you intend actually to select the data for the two other colums. In the example you given fot link_id 4 you expect to get count 2, however the dates for the two records with link_id 4 differ (one is 5.10.2014 the other is 6.10.2014). Which one should be taken for the result?